# Question about prediction: if a variable can predict another variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have a question about the prediction. This question stopped me for a whole afternoon, still do not have an idea on how to solve it. Would you please give me a clue. The question is:

`U_1,U_2` be independent standard normal random variables and set `Z=U_1^2+U_2^2`, `Y=U_1`. Is Z of any value in prediction Y?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

At least intuitively, it definitely should!
Assume Z=4, then Y is likely to have a high absolute value.
Assume Z is close to zero, now Y is definitely small.

What Z will not tell you is any information about whether Y is positive or negative, but you can think of Y as the square root of Z minus the square of a normal random variable, therefore Z is critical in determining Y

Also, please consider changing the U_1, U_2 notation. It makes a very simple question a bit harder to read than it should

Comment: "Assume Z=4, then Y is likely to have a high value"  -- I don't think there's a good basis for this. U1 and U2 may be either positive or negative and either may be the main contributor to Z, or both might be similar in magnitude. If $Z=4$ then $-2\leq U_1 \leq 2$. Now, there is a [greater chance of being in a small interval near $\pm 2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsLHL.png) than in an interval of the same width near 0, and in that sense it's somewhat "predictable" (given Z we can give two intervals one of which is likely to contain Y), but that's a different statement to the one in your answer

Comment: You are absolutelly right, but I do not understand the difference between your claim and mine. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Thank you all. My idea is that when we solve this kind of question, should we consider the E(Y|Z)? If E(Y|Z)=0 then I can say Z could not predict on Y?

Comment: @asdf you said "Y is likely to have a high value". That's demonstrably not the case; the conditional distribution of Y is symmetric -- Y is exactly as likely to be low as it is high.

Comment: @WangWang it depends on what you mean by "predict". If you mean "does E(Y|Z=z) vary with z?" then the answer is "clearly not". If you mean "can I give a (possibly non-simple) prediction interval for the conditional distribution of Y that differs from one I'd give for Y without conditioning on Z?" then the answer is clearly "yes".

Comment: @Glen_b When I said "high value" I meant "high in magnitude", either positive or negative

Comment: Perhaps you could edit it so it says what you intend rather than what it currently says; I doubt that most readers would interpret "high value" as "high in magnitude".

Comment: @WangWang if E(Y|Z) differs from E(Y) then you definitely could use Z to predict Y. Otherwise you cannot use it to predict Y's expectation, but this does not mean it could hold other type of information like, for example, variance